# How to Edit Title, Contributing Artist, Album, Year, etc. info of an MP3, FLAC etc. file in Music in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, mp3, edit, flac

In some situations, I end up with songs in Windows 10's Music folder that just have blanks for all columns containing the song information i.e. the song's title, artist, album, year, etc. The procedure I use to try to resolve this is as follows:

1. In the Music folder, Right-click the song file's name > Click on Properties.
   Under the General tab, under Attributes, Un-check the Read-Only box > Click Apply > Click OK.
2. Again: In the Music folder, Right-click the song file's name > Click on Properties.
   Under the Details tab, you should now be able to change the Title, Contributing Artists, Album, Year, #, etc. as you like > Click Apply > Click OK.

HOWEVER this procedure sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. And in some of the cases when it doesn't work, I can just wait a few minutes and it'll work on a 2nd try, but in other cases, it won't work no matter how many times I try. Does anyone know why this is or what I should do???

Comment: Windows sucks, but it can be edited even for WAV files with Kid3 Audio Tag Editor, kid3.kde.org

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I need to use Audacity to convert a FLAC file to an MP3 file, and then the song info can be edited.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, in case anyone is wondering, you can quickly convert numerous FLAC (or WMA, etc.) files (in an entire folder) to MP3 in Audacity as follows.

1. Copy-paste all the FLAC files to an empty folder on the C: drive.
2. Select all (CTRL-A) the files and right click > Properties to uncheck the read-only box.
3. In Audacity: Tools > Macros > In the "Manage Macros" dialog box, under "Select Macro..." choose "MP3 Conversion" > Click on "Files" > (Then find the folder your files are in and click on it) > Select all (CTRL-A) the files > Open.
4. Now wait and watch the computer screen while the "Manage Macros" dialog box shows each of your FLAC files being converted one by one. Every once in a while a dialog box stating "Invalid sample rate" will open up and give you a few sample rates to choose from. Choose 44,100 every time and click OK.
5. The resultant MP3 files will be in a folder called "Macro Output" visible within the Audacity Macros Files dialog box. Test out a random sample of these files to make sure they're ok and move the files to the original folder. Then you can delete the original FLAC files and the FLAC file copies.

MP3 files may have worse sound quality than FLAC files but I think most people can't hear much of a difference. Also, MP3 files offer the great advantage of taking up less space. I think the average FLAC file is about 20 MB in size while the average MP3 file is 8 MB.